# Button over another in the game engine

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a little red plane above a big green plane:

I have set the red plane for one action, and the green plane for another when i click them.

But when i click one the red (in the game) that click activate both of the planes.

How to deactivate the green plane when the mouse is over the red plane?

Answer (score 4):

If the *Mouse Sensor* is set to *Left Mouse Button*, it will simply register if the mouse button is pressed, regardless where you do it.

You can combine it with a *Mouse Over Sensor* and use an *And Controller*. Then the *Actuator* is only triggered when the mouse is over the right object and LMB is pressed.

[image: Mouse Over]

Comment: I'm curious. Did answer your question?